# What is proper way to call obtainStyledAttributes() in Android custom views

Tags: android, android-custom-view

What is the difference between

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, 0, 0);
```

and

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, defStyleAttr, 0);
```

Comment: Your question helped me find my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"defStyleAttr" is
An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource that supplies defaults values for the TypedArray.  Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

Comment: Would have been better to explain in real use cases what "defStyleAttr" does instead of copy-pasting the doc...